# Time complexity of TreeMultimap operations

Tags: java, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of `put(key, value)`, `get(key)` in TreeMultimap?

It isn't mentioned in the documentation:
http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: Looks like it's backed by a `Map<K, Collection<V>>`.  Hint:  The type of `Collection` you have is specified partially in the name of the multimap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check on [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/search?query=TreeMultimap&n=):

```
@Override public boolean put(K key, V value) {
    return super.put(key, value);
  }
```

`super` is `com.google.common.collect.AbstractMultimap`.

```
  public boolean put(@Nullable K key, @Nullable V value) {
    Collection<V> collection = getOrCreateCollection(key);

    if (collection.add(value)) {
      totalSize++;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

[The data structure that drives this is](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.collections/google-collections/1.0/com/google/common/collect/AbstractMultimap.java#AbstractMultimap.0map):

```
private transient Map<K, Collection<V>> map;
```

The outer map is a `TreeMap`, which you can verify from tracing constructors.

`createCollection` is abstract:

```
 protected abstract Collection<V> createCollection();
```

And the implementation uses `TreeSet`:

```
@Override SortedSet<V> createCollection() {
return (valueComparator == null)
    ? new TreeSet<V>() : new TreeSet<V>(valueComparator);
```

}

Therefore `put` is

1. A `get` into a `TreeMap`
2. A `put` into either a `TreeMap` or `TreeSet`.

Those are `log(n)`, so a `TreeMultimap` is also `log(n)`.